# Converting XML to CSV formate using XSLT

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

In my case, I'm trying to convert the XML to CSV format using XSLT.

But I'm getting the header, which is also iterating and printing again, and I also couldn't add a new line to the values column.

XML input:

```
<EmployeeDetails>
    <Employee>
        <FirstName>harry</FirstName>
        <SecondName>potter</SecondName>
        <Email>harrypotter@gmail.com</Email>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <FirstName>tony</FirstName>
        <SecondName>stark</SecondName>
        <Email>tonystark@gmail.com</Email>
    </Employee>
</EmployeeDetails>
```

My XLST code :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="data" select="//*[not(*)]" />
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$data">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="$data">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The Output i'm getting for the above XSLT code:

> FirstName,SecondName,Email,FirstName,SecondName,Email
> harry,potter,harrypotter@gmail.com,tony,stark,tonystark@gmail.com

Expected output:

```
FirstName,SecondName,Email 
harry,potter,harrypotter@gmail.com
tony,stark,tonystark@gmail.com
```

Any ideas on above xslt, please assist me and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you abandon the attempt to make this completely generic and do :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />

<xsl:template match="/EmployeeDetails">
    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Employee[1]/*">
        <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <!-- data -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Employee">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">,</xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this is assuming there won't be any commas, quotation marks or line breaks within the data. And of course, that all children of `Employee` are leaf nodes.